# Matlab check rerouted links table

Tags: matlab, graph

I have a `links` table as follows:

```
==========================
vl_id    Source    Target
==========================
  1        1         3
  1        1         4
  3        2         3
  3        2         4
```

Different target for the same `vl_id` means that the same message is send to both the targets.

Due to some constraint, the above link table needs to be modified by adding a relay `5` in between and the resulting link table `T` would be as follows:

```
==========================
vl_id    Source    Target
==========================
  1        1         5
  3        2         5
  15       5         3
  15       5         4
  25       5         3
  25       5         4
```

I need to check if all the links present in the `links` table have been included in `T` inspite of the relay. That is, a check to ensure that the end to end connections in `links` are present in `T` as well although through a relay (here `5`).

I have done this so far:

```
%% check 2: are all connections from original graph present in rerouted
temp = find(~ismember(links,T,'rows')) % get rows in links table that are missing from T
x1 = links(find(~ismember(links,T,'rows')),:); % get rows in T that are missing from links
x2 = T(find(~ismember(T,links,'rows')), :);
for ii = 1 : size(x1,1)
    for jj = 1 : size(x2,1)
        if(x1(ii).vl_id == x2(jj).vl_id)
            if(x1(ii).Target == x2(jj).Target)
                disp('same target');
            else

            end
        end
    end
end
```

I feel that this is not the right approach of doing this. Could someone suggest a better way.

Comment: Please specify why you think your code is _not the right approach_.

Comment: `links(~ismember(links,T,'rows'),:)` gives you all the rows that are in `link` ad not present in `T`. What else do you need? and what is the purpose of all the rest of your code?